# Checking the neighbor of the current cell

Tags: java, performance

This is just checking the parameter you enter is a neighbour of the current Cell (which is obtained using `getRow()` and `getColumn()`).

Is there an easier way of doing this? How could I make this more compact and efficient?

```
public boolean isNeighbourOf(Cell c){

 boolean check = false;

 //check for not neighbours
 if(c.getRow() == getRow() && c.getColumn() == getColumn()){
     check = false;
 }

 else if(c.getRow() == getRow() - 1 && c.getColumn() == getColumn() - 1){
     check = false;
 }

 else if(c.getRow() == getRow() + 1 && c.getColumn() == getColumn() - 1){
     check = false;
 }

 else  if(c.getRow() == getRow() - 1 && c.getColumn() == getColumn() + 1){
     check = false;
 }

 else if(c.getRow() == getRow() + 1 && c.getColumn() == getColumn() + 1){
     check = false;
 }

 //check for neighbours
  else if(c.getRow() == getRow() - 1 && c.getColumn() == getColumn()){
     check = true;
 }
  else if(c.getRow() == getRow() + 1 && c.getColumn() == getColumn()){
         check = true;
  }
  else if(c.getRow() == getRow() && c.getColumn() == getColumn() + 1){
         check = true;
  }
  else if(c.getRow() == getRow() && c.getColumn() == getColumn() - 1){
         check = true;
  }
  return check;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously yes, but I'm seriously asking myself, if there's any more complicated way.

With including diagonal neighbors this would do

```
public boolean isNeighbourOf(Cell c) {
    int d1 = Math.abs(c.getRow() - getRow());
    int d2 = Math.abs(c.getColumn() - getColumn());
    return Math.max(d1, d2) == 1;
}
```

For straight line neighbors only use

```
    return d1 + d2 == 1;
```

Here, `d1 + d2` is the distance measured via the "postman metric".

Comment: While I laughed heartily at your comment I would say his way is not complicated, rather it's very simple yet verbose.  Your way is more complicated but way more concise.

Comment: @UncleIroh This is sort of true... but one remarkable complication in the original are the special case returning `false` which are absolutely redundant. My method is only complicated till you think about distance.

Comment: @UncleIroh - There are two kinds of complexity that are relevant here.  The OP's code is simple in terms of the conceptual process, but complex in terms of the code that realizes that process.  In programming, the latter is usually more important than the former, because verbose code with (for example) high cyclomatic complexity has more "opportunity" for bugs.  Or to put this another way, if you have to read the you versions to check that they are correct, then the OP's version is more work.

Comment: Plus the complexity of changing the code, which is also part of the Cyclomatic Complexity I suppose.

Comment: @maaartinus, thank you for such a precise solution. I am new to programming still, so I can come up with solutions, but I need to think about using such steps as yours to reduce the complexity of them!

Comment: @Travisty You're welcome. Everybody was a beginner one day, for me it was when the coal was wood. Get lazy in writing and avoid all repetitive constructs. It'll take time, but it's worth it. Always ask yourself, if it's not too long. But don't go overboard with it. Use local variables to make things simpler. Learn your IDE, it can do a lot. Use SO and CR.

Answer (score 3):

```
return Math.abs(c.getRow   () - getRow   ()) +
       Math.abs(c.getColumn() - getColumn()) == 1;
```

You want to be in the same row and one column apart, or in the same column and one row apart. Computing the absolute value of the difference in row and column numbers tells you how far apart the cells are irrespective of orientation. For horizontal and vertical neighbors these must add up to 1; that is, one of them must be 1 and the other must be 0.

Answer (score 3):

First off, I don't see the point in checking for the true and false cases. Just pick one or the other. Ex: If you know it's not true, then it must be false.

I also think you can simplify your logic. You know that the cell you are checking must be in the same row xor the same column. If that first check is true, then you know that the cell you are checking must be within 1 row or column of the current cell.

```
if(c.getRow() == getRow() ^ c.getColumn() == getColumn)
   if(Math.abs(getRow() - c.getRow) == 1 || Math.abs(getColumn() - c.getColumn) == 1)
     return true;
return false;
```